# Matplotlib Scatterplot with 4 visual encondings

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

The initial step is a pandas Dataframe with several columns.

Th second step I did is to convert some columns of this Dataframe in a Numpy array using `to_numpy()` function.

I retrieve something like:

```
[[100 200 3.5 1] [100 200 3.5 1] [100 300 6.2 1] [200 125 4.2 1] [100 300 6.2 1] [100 200 3.5 1]]
```

Where the first element imagine that is an origin id
the second element is a destiny id
the 3rd is the distance between origin a destiny
and the 4th is just a counter (1 element) (I have included it just because I think that could be required to count elements. Just ignore it if your proposed solution doesn't use it)

I would like to have a scatterplot with the following specifications:

- origing_id in x axis
- destiny_id in y axis
- color of the scatter dot in a warm scale that
  indicates distance between both points (3rd element)
- size of the
  scatter dot depends on the number of pairs of    origins_id
  /destiny_id we have.for example we have three 100 200
  combinations. So its size should be bigger that the one for
  combintion 200 125 that only has one entry.

I have tried but I'm not able to include all prerequisites in this plot.
How this could be achieved in matplotlib? Or is there any other easier approach using pandas directly?

Comment: These are two different tasks. One is to update your counter column for the pairs in panda, the other to create a 4D plot in matplotlib. I suggest you focus on one question here.

Comment: I think that maybe it is a misunderstood. Counter column goal is only to be used by a king of count() function, Similar approach that follows a clasical map-reduce algorithm. I have just included in case it helps. My main question is related to the plot

Comment: I suggest in this case that you modify your example and update the counter numbers to make clear that this is not part of the question.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I have included a comment to clarify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirements correctly, this should do the trick:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[100,200,3.5,1],[100,200,3.5,1],[100,300,6.2,1],[200,125,4.2,1],[100,300,6.2,1],[100,200,3.5,1]])

unique, counts =  np.unique(data, axis=0,  return_counts=True)  
x = unique[:,0]
y = unique[:,1]
c = unique[:,2]
## figure out a nice looking scaling factor here
#  and remember that the scatter point size is supposed to be an area,
#  hence squaring a base factor is ideal
s = (counts*10)**2 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sca = ax.scatter(x,y,c=c,s=s)
plt.colorbar(sca)

plt.show()
```

which yields:

[image: a scatter plot]